# Why is my WP website redirecting the register page, to the login page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, plugins, account

I have somewhat recently become the admin for a friend's website. When I came on he had about 80 different plugins and I have recently gotten rid of a lot of the useless one. The website was working perfectly fine afterwards. Then I found out (a bit before the WordPress 5.5 update) that the register page wasn't working properly. I went ahead and cleared a lot more things and have been troubleshooting it nearly everyday. The website is now at the point where you can go to the login page, but attempting to go to the register page will redirect the user back to the login page. If I visit as an admin I can access the page, but the form displays the text that I am already registered (correctly, but not useful).

The plugins that are currently enabled related to logins are: Ultimate Member, Gamipress, Jetpack, Loginizer, and various Gamipress and Ultimate member integration plugins. If you want to see the site for yourself you can find it here:

https://www.plagueleague.com/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment for more information, so I use the answers... In admin, then "Settings", then "General", does the box "Membership: Anyone can register" is checked? If the answer is no, I think that redirects to the login page.

Comment: The membership setting is checked.